# Unable to find php binary

Tags: linux, php5

PHP is running fine with apache on my server. I want to use it from command line but I am unable to find the binary:

```
root@....:~# whereis php
php:
root@....:~# whereis php5
php5: /etc/php5 /usr/lib/php5 /usr/share/php5
```

There is no binary in the above folders.

Further, I did a

```
cd /usr
find . | grep "bin.*php"
```

and got 0 results. How to locate the php binary?!

### EDIT

I reinstalled php5-cli (apparently went okay, but still unable to use it!)

```
root@...:/usr# apt-get install --reinstall php5-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/2490kB of archives.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 30026 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace php5-cli 5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.6 (using .../php5-cli_5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.6_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement php5-cli ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up php5-cli (5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.6) ...

root@...:/usr# php5-cli
bash: php5-cli: command not found
root@...:/usr# whereis php5-cli
php5-cli:
```

Comment: Works now. After installing php5-cli, the command is php5, not php5-cli which I was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some distributions have Apache2, CGI and CLI SAPIs in separate packages. For example, on Debian, you would have `php5-cli`, `php5-cgi`, and `libapache2-mod-php5`.

To run PHP scripts from command line, you need the "CLI" package.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the binary is located here:

- `/usr/bin/php5`

Sometimes it is also under

- `/user/sbin/php5`

If the command is restricted to superusers only.

Probably the binary got deleted on your machine...

Comment: I couldn't find /usr/bin/php5 or /usr/sbin/php5 :(. Do I need to reinstall php?

Comment: yep, unfortunately, I would say so.

Comment: thanks for the help. but reinstalling php5 did not help .. had to install php5-cli.

Answer (score 0):

This command will search for any `php` binaries in your system, even if it's outside of $PATH:

`sudo find -type f -name php -executable -exec file -i '{}' \; | grep 'x-executable; charset=binary'`